# Java singltone exception Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: java

i have Server side i tried to make it Singeltone in order to accses server metodtds from another classes, but when i run server main and then i do `Server.getInstance()` from another class it throws this expection:

> Exception in thread "main" 
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

i tried a lot of things but its not working

```
 private static Server serverinstance = null;
        private static Object obj=new Object();

        public Server() throws IOException {
            server = new ServerSocket(222);
            hash = new HashMap<String, SocketData>();
        }


        public static Server getInstance() throws IOException {
            synchronized (obj) {
                if (serverinstance == null) {
                    serverinstance = new Server();
                    serverinstance.listenServer();
                }
                return serverinstance;
            }
        }

        private void listenServer() throws IOException {
            while (flag) {
                ans = server.accept();
                if (serverinstance != null)
                    new EchoThread(serverinstance, ans);
            }
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            Server.getInstance();
        }

    Class A()
    {
    public A()
    {
    Server.getInstance();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running both on the same VM? Looks like you are running main program that will start a JVM and then from another JVM calling `Server.getInstance()`. If that is the case then you are going to create tow separate `Server` object that will try to open the same port.

Comment: i running the server with main and then i running class A with main

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer. That is because another program is already using port 222, so your program is unable to listen on it. If that doesn't work, try switching 222 to something different, like maybe 8000 or 9999, basically any number from 1000-65535 (0-65535 if you are on Windows)

Comment: @mat JVM bindexception means that the port is already bound to. If you tried changing the port multiple times and it did not work, then your laptop has some issues. If it is Linux, post the output of `netstat`

Comment: @mat ok, I don't remember the equivalent of netstat, but you can find it easily online (it's a built in command)

Comment: and when i tried to accses the vairable from another class its null so the getinstance create one more serversocket on the same port and this is throws the exception

Answer (score 0):

Java singleton guarantees one instance only per JVM and per ClassLoader.

In your case you are loading the same `Server` class into two different JVM and Classloaders by invoking two separate `main` methods. This causes the `Server` constructor to be called twice that in turn tries to create two `ServerSocket` on the same 222 port.

One quick solution is to have class `A` be created directly or indirectly from the `main` method that is calling `Server.getInstance();`.

Comment: Class A needs to be the Client Class so if i want to running client few times how to do it?